# Django forms - checkbox group with dropdowns

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Can someone tell me how to write CustomWidget/CustomField for a checkbox group with drop-downs in it using Django forms?

1. All checkboxes should have the same name (Checkbox group)
2. Each checkbox should have a drop down as child element (same dropdown for all checkboxes)
3. CustomWidget/CustomField should accept options= [] param to generate checkbox group
4. Checkbox group with required=True validation

[image]

Ex. Case: Text boxes will show Dimensions and each Dimension should have a drop down with list of aggregate functions in it.

Comment: This is really unclear. What is a "checkbox group of dropdowns"? What do the boxes in your picture have to do with the selects?

Comment: Every checkbox field should contain one dropdown

Comment: What should those dropdowns do? A usage example would be (no pun intended) useful.

Comment: Textboxes will show Dimensions and Dropdowns is meant for selecting Aggregate functions on it. So, I have to get list of selected Dimensions and its functions at the same time. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In forms.py**

```
class DynamicForm(forms.Form):

    options = [
    ('Textbox1', 'Textbox1'),
    ('Textbox2', 'Textbox2'),
    ...
    ]

    dynamic_data = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=options)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DynamicForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for i in range(1,len(self.options)+1):
            self.fields['dd_func_'+str(i)] = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices= [
                            ('average', 'average'),
                            ('sum', 'sum')], initial='sum', required=False)

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        try:
            field = self.fields[name]
        except KeyError:
            raise KeyError('Key %r not found in Form' % name)
        return forms.forms.BoundField(self, field, name)
```

**In views.py**

```
from app.forms import DynamicForm

def create_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        dynamic_form = DynamicForm(request.POST)
        ...
        ...
    else:
        dynamic_form = DynamicForm()
    return render(request, 'form.html', {
        'dynamic_form': dynamic_form
        })
```

**In templates/form.html**

```
{% load myfilters %}
{{ dynamic_form.dynamic_data.errors }}
{% for checkbox in dynamic_form.dynamic_data|checkboxiterator %} 
    {{ checkbox }}
    {% with c=forloop.counter|stringformat:"s" %}
        {% with c='dd_func_'|add:c %}
            {{ dynamic_form|lookup:c }}
        {% endwith %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

**In templatetags/myfilters.py**

https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2159/

and

```
@register.filter
def lookup(f, name):
    try:        
    return f[name]
    except KeyError:
    return None
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [MultiValueField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.MultiValueField) and [MultiWidget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.MultiWidget).

You can make the MultiValueField **init** method accept any options you want to build all the options and use custom logic in the MultiWidget to render all the checkboxes and selects and compress/decompress the values input by the user to a suitable representation, like a dict {checkbox_name: operation}.

Comment: I can but in about 8 hours... So that's after the grace period, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this should do it.

Depending on what you have in your views, simply place some list in your_list as context. Depending on how many items there are in the list, it will create one of these checkbox-list combinations for each one.

```
{% for number in your_list %}
    <div class="check_box" id="check_box_{{ number }}">
        <input id="cb_{{ number }}" name="cb_{{ number }}" type="checkbox"><label for="cb_{{ number }}">textbox {{ number }}</label>
        <select class="some_class">
            <option value="1">Sum</option>
            <option value="2">Difference</option>
            <option value="3">Whatever</option>
        </select>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The output will look like this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/3vetooLp/1/